# finding the index of the largest element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I want to write a code that returns the index of the largest element in a given array. However, when I try compiling, I get a message that I can't seem to understand. Although I have done the things that the error message tells, it keeps telling me to fix them. Please help this novice programmer!

---

```
public class largest {
    int[] array = new int[10];
    array[0] = 100;
    array[1] = 200;
    array[2] = 300;
    array[3] = 400;
    array[4] = 500;
    array[5] = 600;
    array[6] = 700;
    array[7] = 800;
    array[8] = 900;
    array[9] = 1000;
    int index;

    public static void main(String args) {

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if (array[i] < array[i+1]) {
                index = i + 1;
            } else {
                index = i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(index);
    }
}
```

---

And below is the compilation message.

---

```
largest.java:3: error: ']' expected
    array[0] = 100;
      ^
largest.java:3: error: ';' expected
    array[0] = 100;
       ^
largest.java:3: error: illegal start of type
    array[0] = 100;
         ^
largest.java:3: error: <identifier> expected
    array[0] = 100;
          ^
```

---

And this continues for all indices.

Comment: Side note: I wholeheartedly recommend you to study some basic tutorials regarding the structure of java classes. And also on "how to name things" in java (your class names should always start with upper case).

Answer (score 4):

This type of initialization can't be done outside of a method :

```
array[0] = 100;
array[1] = 200;
array[2] = 300;
array[3] = 400;
array[4] = 500;
array[5] = 600;
array[6] = 700;
array[7] = 800;
array[8] = 900;
array[9] = 1000;
```

Either move the assignments into your main of change to

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

to

```
int[] array = {100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000};
```

BTW, in addition to this compilation error, your code doesn't do what it is supposed to do. It will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (since `array[i+1]` will be out of bounds when i reaches 9). In order to find the index of the largest element you must maintain a variable holding the current maximum and compare it to all the elements of the array.

```
public static void main(String args) {
    int max = array[0];
    index = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            index = i;
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(index);
}
```

Comment: while initializing array aren't we we use `{ }` instead of `( )`? Dose it work (I'm not sure thats why I am asking) or it is a typo?

Answer (score 1):

There are few corrections:

```js
public class largest {
  //move inside main() from here
  int[] array = new int[10];
  array[0] = 100;
  array[1] = 200;
  array[2] = 300;
  array[3] = 400;
  array[4] = 500;
  array[5] = 600;
  array[6] = 700;
  array[7] = 800;
  array[8] = 900;
  array[9] = 1000;
  int index; //required default value
  //move inside main() till here

  public static void main(String args) { //missing [] symbol

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (array[i] < array[i + 1]) {
        index = i + 1;
      } else {
        index = i;
      }
      i++;
    }
    System.out.println(index);
  }
}
```

You may try this example:

```js
public class largest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {
      345, 768, 95, 345, 678
    }; //array with default elements
    int index = -1, high = array[0], i = 0;
    for (int e: array) { //loop in every element
      if (e > high) { //check for highest value
        index = i; //assign index of the highest value till now
        high = e; //assign the highest value till now
      }
      i++; //next index
    }
    System.out.println(index); //-1 if not found
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900};
    System.out.println(highestValue(array));
}

public static int highestValue(int[] arr) {

    int index = 0;
    int highestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        if(temp > highestValue) {
            highestValue = temp;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```